# I want to reduce the amount of lines this file has

Tags: flutter

I've been trying to reduce the length of the lines of code in this file, and I don't know how. I tried not repeating the same code twice in some parts, but I can't seem to make this a function.

The code I want to make a function is the one that is on the search bar and the delete button from it, I searched for a solution on how to make it a function or something that worked, but i didn't find something. It was mostly re-writing my whole code so I can put the solution.

The code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:velneoapp/api/modelos/api_model_partes.dart';
import 'package:velneoapp/views/partes/detalle_de_parte.dart';

class PartesView extends StatefulWidget {
  const PartesView({super.key});

  @override
  State<PartesView> createState() => _PartesViewState();
}

class Debouncer {
  int? milliseconds;
  VoidCallback? action;
  Timer? timer;

  run(VoidCallback action) {
    if (null != timer) {
      timer!.cancel();
    }
    timer = Timer(
      const Duration(milliseconds: Duration.millisecondsPerSecond),
      action,
    );
  }
}

class _PartesViewState extends State<PartesView> {
  String string = "";
  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  Partes? dataFromAPI;
  final _debouncer = Debouncer();
  bool _isLoading = true;
  List<Prt> valores = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    _getData();
    setState(() {});
    super.initState();
  }

  _getData() async {
    try {
      String url =
          "https://demoapi.velneo.com/verp-api/vERP_2_dat_dat/v1/vta_ped_g?page%5Bsize%5D=20&fields=id,clt,emp&api_key=api123";
      http.Response res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        log("Correcto");
        dataFromAPI = Partes.fromJson(json.decode(res.body));
        _isLoading = false;
        setState(() {});
      } else {
        log("${res.statusCode}");
        throw ("Error durante la conexión");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log("Error antes de conectarse => ${e.toString()}");
    }
    valores = dataFromAPI!.vtaPedGs;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Partes"),
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : Column(
              children: [
                //Search Bar to List of typed Subject
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: TextField(
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                    controller: _searchController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _searchController.text = "";
                          string = _searchController.text;
                        },
                      ),
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      hintText: 'Buscar...',
                    ),
                    onChanged: (string) {
                      _debouncer.run(
                        () {
                          setState(
                            () {
                              valores = dataFromAPI!.vtaPedGs
                                  .where(
                                    (u) => (u.id
                                            .toString()
                                            .toLowerCase()
                                            .contains(string.toLowerCase()) ||
                                        u.clt
                                            .toString()
                                            .toLowerCase()
                                            .contains(string.toLowerCase()) ||
                                        u.emp
                                            .toLowerCase()
                                            .contains(string.toLowerCase())),
                                  )
                                  .toList();
                            },
                          );
                          log("valores: $valores");
                        },
                      );
                    }, //toLowerCase().contains(
                    //string.toLowerCase(),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    itemCount: valores.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setId(dataFromAPI!.vtaPedGs[index].id);
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    const DetalleDePartesView()),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Card(
                          child: ClipPath(
                            clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                                  left:
                                      BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 5),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      "ID: ${valores[index].id}",
                                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Cliente: ${valores[index].clt}",
                                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Empresa: ${valores[index].emp}",
                                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

As I said, I tried to do a function on the code I repeated twice, but it didn't work

Comment: There isn't really that much duplication I would say. It looks pretty fine as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one minor thing you could do to cut some lines is to change

```
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "ID: ${valores[index].id}",
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
            Text(
              "Cliente: ${valores[index].clt}",
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
            Text(
              "Empresa: ${valores[index].emp}",
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

to

```
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          for (final text in [
            "ID: ${valores[index].id}",
            "Cliente: ${valores[index].clt}",
            "Empresa: ${valores[index].emp}"
          ])
            Text(
              text,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: This does reduce the amount of lines of the code and it works, thx!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write the code you can just take the come code snippet and make it's function, pass some values if there's some requirements is there.

Like here's the code for your search textField:

```
Widget searchField(){
  return TextField(
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
    controller: _searchController,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
      suffixIcon: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          _searchController.text = "";
          string = _searchController.text;
        },
      ),
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      hintText: 'Buscar...',
    ),
    onChanged: (string) {
      _debouncer.run(
            () {
          setState(
                () {
              valores = dataFromAPI!.vtaPedGs
                  .where(
                    (u) => (u.id
                    .toString()
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .contains(string.toLowerCase()) ||
                    u.clt
                        .toString()
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .contains(string.toLowerCase()) ||
                    u.emp
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .contains(string.toLowerCase())),
              )
                  .toList();
            },
          );
          log("valores: $valores");
        },
      );
    }, //toLowerCase().contains(
    //string.toLowerCase(),
  );
}
```

Just like the last three Text widgets that has the same style just different values:

```
Widget myText(String text) {
  return Text(
    text,
    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
  );
}
```

and call it with passing your text to display `myText("ID: ${valores[index].id}")` and `myText("Cliente: ${valores[index].id}")`.

And i don't know about your use-case but why is there Container inside a ClipPath inside a Card, i know you want the decoration and designing but all that can be possible with the Container widget, Explore widgets..!

Hope this'll help you...